# Calling a parent function from within an iframe WITHOUT using parent.someFunction()?

Tags: javascript

Is this possible?

The function `someMethod` is a member of the parent window.

iframe content:

```
<a href="" onclick="Something.call('someMethod', 'Some data'); ">Send some data</a>
```

Any way to call `someMethod` without doing...

```
<a href="" onclick="parent.Something.call('someMethod', 'Some data'); ">Send some data</a>
```

UPDATE:

Basically I have a presentation layer inside an iframe which has content that calls a metric api function to send a metric to the server.  the iframe is in the parent window.  The content (presentation) was previously developed without using a parent.SomeAPIMethod() call.  How do I intercept the api call from the parent layer? Any way to do this without changing all the metric calls within the content?

Comment: You could have the function "Something" in the iframe content that basicly just does parent.Something.call

Comment: Also meant to mention that the iframe link needs to not change.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code here. From what I can tell, you're invoking the function `Something` (i.e., with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)), with `'Some data'` as the first argument and the string `'someMethod'` as the `this`-value. Is that correct? You say that your ultimate goal is to run a function called `someMethod`, so I can only assume that the function `Something` uses its `this` value to access the function `someMethod` by name. Is all that correct? It seems very strange.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid that?

Comment: I suspect you may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/186560). Please edit your question to explain what you really want to accomplish, what your current problem is, and why you feel that you can't use `parent`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I described the issue in a little more detail above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use into a frame or iframe:

1. **window.parent.someFunction(parameters)** to call a function in a window up one
   level.
2. **window.top.someFunction(parameters)** to call a function the maximum
   level window. In others words, the container window of all.

For example, this is the JavaScript in the window container:

```
function someFunction(msg) {
    alert(msg +"!!!");
}
```

In the frame or iframe you can use with a button:

```
<button onclick="window.top.someFunction('message');">Trigger function</button>
```

However, if you want to use a "alias", then you can use this JavaScript:

```
var aliasFn = window.top.someFunction;
```

After, when you want to use it:

```
<button onclick="aliasFn('message');">Trigger function</button>
```

Hope that helps.